# Symfony 2, Can I share the login between frontend and backend?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to share the user's session between the frontend and the backend. For example, if you access to domain.com/login and you login succesfully, you should be able to access (if you have enough privileges) to domain.com/admin/, without a new login. The other way is, if you access to domain.com/admin/login and sign in succesfully, when you go to domain.com/, you should be already identified, without a new login action.

So, the question is, how can I share the login for the same domain?

My security.yml:

```
    providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern: /admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path:     admin_login
            check_path:     admin_login_check
            default_target_path: admin_home
        logout:
            path:           admin_logout
            target:         admin_login
        anonymous:    true
        security:     true
        context:      application
        remember_me:
            key: XXXXXXXXXXXX
            lifetime: 86400
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        security:     true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And my config.yml

    `session:
        handler_id:  ~
        cookie_path: /
        name: __XXXXXXX`

PD: I'm using the FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `context` to "application" on your `main` firewall should work ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context)). E.g.

```
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    logout: true
    anonymous: true
    security: true
    context: application
```